# Search line in QtreeWidget Pyside2

Tags: python, pipeline, maya, pyside2, qtreewidget

QLineEdit with  search functionality that you will search items by name in QtreeWidgets. would be cool with Toggling widget visibility and text prediction

list = ["child", "mother", "father"]

value = self.QlineEdit.text()
for e in range(len(list)):

```
if value.lower() == list.lower():
    
    self.treewidget.show()
```

super random code but i dont have any idea how can i will start with this.

[image]

Comment: Start by looking at [`findItems()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#findItems).

Comment: items = self.treeWidget.findItems(list , Qt.MatchRecursive,0)